# TypeError: vocabulary does not contain the UNK token

Tags: botframework

My bot is using Orchestrator to choose between QnA Maker and LUIS. The model folder + contents and the snapshot are generated using the BF CLI using this example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-orchestrator?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=js

When I run my application locally everything goes well and the `OrchestratorRecognizer` returns the expected result.

When I deploy my code to the Azure Web App I get the following error:

```
TypeError: vocabulary does not contain the UNK token.
at OrchestratorRecognizer._initializeModel (/node_modules/botbuilder-ai-orchestrator/lib/orchestratorRecognizer.js:272:35)
at OrchestratorRecognizer.<anonymous> (/node_modules/botbuilder-ai-orchestrator/lib/orchestratorRecognizer.js:143:18)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at /node_modules/botbuilder-ai-orchestrator/lib/orchestratorRecognizer.js:15:71
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at __awaiter (/node_modules/botbuilder-ai-orchestrator/lib/orchestratorRecognizer.js:11:12)
at OrchestratorRecognizer.recognize (/node_modules/botbuilder-ai-orchestrator/lib/orchestratorRecognizer.js:123:16)
at EmptyBot.<anonymous> (/home/site/wwwroot/lib/bot.js:61:65)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at fulfilled (/home/site/wwwroot/lib/bot.js:7:58)
```

Using SSH to look into the files in the Azure Web App I can't find any obvious differences between the files on the server and my local files.

Changing the SnapShotFile, ModelFolder or VocabFile (in the model folder `config.json`) variables gets me an "File or path not found error" so all the paths seem to be configured right.

Also the `vocab.txt` files contains `[UNK]` which is set as the `unk_token` in `tokenizer_config.json`.

I'm running into this problem for a few days now, if you have any idea what might cause this issue or where to start looking I would greatly appreciate it.